# Bootstrap Modal Loading Improper Alignment and Cut Off Page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using Bootstrap modal to load a thumbnail at a larger size in a pop-up on my website. The code has worked perfectly the past year and a half and I just noticed now it is messed up. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S1w4.png) The modal now loads half cut off the page all the way to the right so I am assuming its something to do with the CSS but I cannot pinpoint it. I did not change anything to my knowledge that would create this effect. The page is active and at the address here: www.thekdesignco.com/portfolio

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `left: 0;` to `.modal.fade .modal-dialog` in your css at line 69.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be a simple fix. I tried a couple things with no luck, but you nailed it.